# How to remove some rows from a Pandas dataframe to balance it

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a csv file and after reading it with pandas it has the following structure:

```
file_path, label
   -        -
```

The labels are only zeros and ones, and the frequency count is as follows:

```
data["labels"].value_counts()

0    197664
1     78444
```

I would like to remove an amount of rows which has the value 0, lets say 20k for example so that the frequency counts will have these values.

```
data["labels"].value_counts()

0    195664
1     78444
```

Comment: 20k rows of label 0 should be removed on what condition? is it simple first 20k rows?

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar Assume I need to move 20k rows that are having the label 0, the last 20k rows in the DataFrame

Comment: can you try my answer and let me know if that works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can drop the last 20K rows on some condition using pandas `drop`.

```
df.drop(df[df.labels == 0].index[-20000:], inplace=True)
```

Comment: This worked! But I have to make sure that the label datatype is an integer not an object. Thank you so much

Comment: @Omar I am glad, I could help you!

Answer (score 1):

```
mydict = {
  "file_path" : ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e" , "f", "g"],
  "label" : [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(mydict)
```

|  | file_path | label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | 0 |
| 1 | b | 1 |
| 2 | c | 0 |
| 3 | d | 1 |
| 4 | e | 1 |
| 5 | f | 1 |
| 6 | g | 0 |

if your labels are 1 or 0 and you want get only "1" label, you can group your dataset by "label" column and then use get_group() :

```
get_1 = df.groupby("label").get_group(1)
get_1
```

|  | file_path | label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | b | 1 |
| 3 | d | 1 |
| 4 | e | 1 |
| 5 | f | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

Usually I do split then `concat`

```
df1 = df.iloc[:20000]
df2 = df.drop(df1.index)
new = pd.concat([df1[df1['labels'] != 0], df2])
```